# problem in swiftUI , trying to use images in list

Tags: swift, swiftui

[view model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o1h3Y.png)

[the list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S7kvz.png)

[the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2U9sc.png)

Hello, in those pictures above, I want to use the list I did to see the images in numerous view by using the view model. The problem I think is that I am not using the good wordings in line 19 of the view model. Because of the wording I use, it says that "Catego" has no member "im" but in fact there is a member called im in the list .

the viewModel :

```
import Foundation
 import FirebaseAuth
 import Firebase
 import FirebaseStorage
import SwiftUI


 class CameraViewModel: ObservableObject {

     @Published var caption: String = ""
    var catt : [Catego] = categoData
     @Published var image: Image = Image(systemName: IMAGE_PHOTO)
     @Published var isLoading = false
     var imageData: Data = Data()
     var errorString = ""


     @Published var showAlert: Bool = false
     @Published var showImagePicker: Bool = false


     func sharePost(completed: @escaping() -> Void,  onError: @escaping(_ errorMessage: String) -> Void) {
        if !caption.isEmpty && !imageData.isEmpty  {
              //AuthService.signupUser(username: username, email: email, password: password, imageData: imageData, onSuccess: completed, onError: onError)
            Api.Post.uploadPost(caption: caption, imageData: imageData,catt: catt, onSuccess: completed, onError: onError)

           } else {
               showAlert = true
               errorString = "Please fill in all fields"
           }
}
}
```

the list :

```
struct Catego: Codable,Hashable, Identifiable{
    var id = UUID()
    var im : String
    var title : String

}

var categoData  = [
    Catego(im: (IMAGE_CATEGORIE_BAG),title: "Plastic Bag"),
    Catego(im: (IMAGE_CATEGORIE_BOTTLE), title: "Plastic Bottle"),
    Catego(im: (IMAGE_CATEGORIE_FILTER), title: "Cigarette Filter"),
    Catego(im : (IMAGE_CATEGORIE_CAN), title: "Aluminium Can"),
    Catego(im: (IMAGE_CATEGORIE_BAGC),title : "Paper Bag"),
    Catego(im: (IMAGE_CATEGORIE_CAP), title: "Bottle Cap")
]
```

the line where there is the problem :

```
Image(cameraViewModel.catt.im)
```

Comment: You can post your code here. Don't post image of code.

Comment: You can't see the images ?

Comment: It's not because I can't see it, that's the way you should follow to ask questions here, read through the guidelines. You'll get down-voted if you keep doing this.

Comment: Ok sorry, I'm new to the forum

Comment: No issues, everyone was new once.

Answer (score 0):

```
var catt : [Catego] = categoData
```

This is a list and you are accessing this as an object. You should use the index for which you want to show the data like this:

```
let index = 0 // Modify this as per your needs. 
Image(cameraViewModel.catt[index].im)
```

That said, if you're using this in the list, you can possible iterate over the array like this:

```
List(cameraViewModel.catt) { catItem in
    Image(catItem.im)
}
```